# 複数のタブ区切りファイルに対して同じ行を取り出して新たなフォルダにまとめるのに最適な言語

Tags: python, c, shellscript

ディレクトリ内にある複数の行列データが保存されたタブ区切りの”複数の”ファイル(以下、datファイル)から、ある特定の行を取り出し、**取り出した順に行データを並べて新たにdatファイル**を作りたいです。
Python/シェルスクリプト/C どれで作ると良いでしょうか。datデータはLinuxのディレクトリ内にあります。

求めている手法の「最適」条件
Linux上のディレクトリで動作する言語（導入しやすい言語_ex.>pythonの場合はpythonスクリプトで書く必要がある？）、プログラムが簡易、処理速度が早い

### datファイルの形式

タブで区切られた小数点数の行列データからなるテキストファイルです。最初の行がアルファベットや記号で列データの見出しになっています。その各見出しの下に小数点数が数百並んでいるデータになります。

```
# x y z  
1.0 2.1 -5.4 8.2
0.0 23.4 4.4 3.4
... (以下数百行続く)
```

追記(2018/06/30)

## タブではなく、複数スペースによる区切りファイルでした。

#[スペース18個]x[スペース19個]y[スペース19個]z
[スペース6個]1.0[スペース5個]2.1[スペース5個]-5.4[スペース5個]8.2
[スペース6個]0.0[スペース5個]23.4[スペース5個]4.4[スペース5個]3.4

... (以下数百行続く)

Comment: 「datファイル」という決まった形式があるわけではないので、中身がどんなデータなのか(単純なテキストorバイナリ)なども質問文に含めてもらうと回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 有難うございます。タブで仕切られた数(小数)の行列データです一番上の行にアルファベットと文字で（ 例＞　# x y u といった）列データの見出しがあり、その各見出しの下に数(小数)が数百並んでいるデータになります。

Comment: 質問は後からでも「編集」できるので、コメントしてもらった内容を含め、必要となりそうな情報を追記してみてください。

Comment: awkしか使ったことがないですが、awkで十分だと思います。

Comment: datファイルの形式を追加してくれた方、ありがとうございます。

Comment: ファイル形式については詳細を追記してもらいましたが、何をもって「最適」と見なすかが提示されていないので、結局『どの方法でも解決出来てあとは使う人の選択次第』になってしまう気がします。

Comment: 確かにそうですね。素人なりの感覚ですが、「最適条件」を追記しました。

Comment: "ある特定の列を取り出し"の条件はなんでしょう？

Comment: list_01_01_1 , list_01_01_2, list_01_01_3, ......といった複数あるdatファイルから同じx行番目のデータを抜き出す。と言う意味です。ある特定の＝同じ行に存在するデータです。例えば、list_01_01_1 , list_01_01_2, list_01_01_3, …に対してそれぞれ３行目を抜き出します。list_01_01_1 の３行目のデータが[1.0 2.1 -5.4 8.2], list_01_01_2の３行目のデータが[8.0 5.4 -1.9 7.2], list_01_01_3の３行目のデータが[4.4 2.4 -8.9 0.1],....であれば, その３行目のデータをとりだした順に(ファイル名の末の数字( _1, _2, _3, .... )の昇順に)並べて１つのファイルにまとめる。

Comment: 質問のタイトルが"複数のタブ区切りファイルに対して同じ列を取り出して"となっているので、質問を訂正したほうが良さそうですね。

Answer (score 2):

datファイルがタブ区切りファイルであれば、シェルスクリプトが良いと思います。

[タブ区切りファイルの例](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) を org.dat とした場合、
以下のシェルコマンドで組みあわせで、列を抽出しソートできます。
(3列目を抽出しソートする場合)

```
# .(カレントディレクトリ)配下のdatファイルからヘッダ部を取り除き1つにまとめ,
# 3列目を抽出, ソート
# 結果をnew.datに保存
find . -type f -name "*.dat" -exec tail -n +2 {} \; | cut -f 3 | sort -n > new.dat
```

Comment: すみません。複数のdatファイルでしたね。修正しました。

Comment: はい、操作の対象は複数のファイルです。ありがとうございます。試してみます！

Comment: 現在デバック中です…new.datファイルに吐き出されず、コマンドラインに表示されます。また、| cut -f 3 | の｜はどんな意味があるのでしょうか。

Comment: パイプといいます。左のコマンドの実行結果を、右のコマンドの入力として使うという意味になります。"find〜\;"コマンドの実行結果を"cut"コマンドに渡し、さらにその実行結果を"sort"コマンドに渡し、最後にその結果をnew.datファイルに出力しています。(例えば、右のサイトを参照してください。 https://eng-entrance.com/linux-pipeline)

Comment: ｜は便利ですね。ありがとうございます。sortはせずに、読み取ったdatファイル順にそのままnew.datに入れたい場合はどうすればよいでしょうか。| cut -f 3 > new.dat では実行されなかったです。

Comment: 問題の切り分けのためにコマンドをパイプで繋がずに1つづつ実行し、意図した結果が表示されるか確認した方が良いと思います。まずは、find . -type f -name "*.dat" -exec tail -n +2 {} \; の結果が全datファイルのデータ部分が出力されるか確認してください。出力されていれば、上記コマンドに " | cut -f 3"を追加して実行し、3列目だけが出力されるか確認してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。find . -type f -name "*.dat" -exec tail -n +2 {} \; の結果が全datファイルのデータ部分は出力されています。" | cut -f 3"を追加して実行しましたが３列目のみ抽出は出来ませんでした。データとしてはfind . -type f -name "*.dat" -exec tail -n +2 {} \; の結果と変化はありません。

Comment: もしかしたら、 datファイルがタブ区切りではなく、スペース区切りなのかもしれません。ご確認ください。もし、スペース区切りであれば、 cut -d ' ' -f 3 とすれば、スペース1文字を区切り文字として cut されます。

Comment: すみません、確かにタブではなく、データ区切りとして用いられていたのはスペースでした。例のデータを用いると…
#[スペース18個]x[スペース19個]y[スペース19個]z  
[スペース6個]1.0[スペース5個]2.1[スペース5個]-5.4[スペース5個]8.2
[スペース6個]0.0[スペース5個]23.4[スペース5個]4.4[スペース5個]3.4
... (以下数百行続く)

Comment: tr -s ' ' で複数のスペースを1つのスペースに置換できます。find . -type f -name "*.dat" -exec tail -n +2 {} \; | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' '  -f 3   でどうでしょうか?

Comment: 複数のファイルに対して３列目のデータのみが取り出せました。コメントで「列」と書いてしまったのですが、抽出したいのは3行目のデータです。「行」です。申し訳ありません。tr -s ' ' のコマンドは上手く反映されていることが確認出来ました。

Comment: 3行目を抽出するなら、 find . -type f -name "*.dat" -exec sed -n 3p {} \;  で実現できそうです。

Answer (score 2):

あくまで一般論になりますが、生産性の高さと、処理速度が速いことが トレードオフの関係なので、楽に作りたいのであれば、まずはシェルスクリプトが良いと思います。

ただ、例えば、dat ファイルが数万ファイルある、もしくは、容量がすごく大きいといった場合は、「処理経過をログに出力したい」など、他の要件がでてくるかもしれません。

そういった「想定外の要件に対応すること」も想定すると、Pythonなどのプログラミング言語のほうがいろいろ出来るので良い気がします。

生産性を重視する場合は、積極的に C を選択する理由は思いつきませんが、処理速度やメモリの効率化が重要な場合は、C を選ぶのがいいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

Python3だと以下のように書けます。python/シェルスクリプト/C どれで作るかは好みの問題だけでしょう。

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

dfs = (pd.read_csv(f, delim_whitespace=True)['x'] for f in Path('.').glob('*.dat'))
pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True).sort_values().to_csv('all.dat', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Comment: Yasuhiroさん＞ありがとうございます。Pythonでも試してみたいと思います。コードを実行させる環境はLinuxなので、Pythonスクリプトでexeファイルを作るべきでしょうか？

Comment: pathlibを使っているのでpython3.4以降が必要です。exeファイルを作る必要はなくて 'python3 ファイル名.py" で実行します。pandasをインストールする必要があるのでubuntuであれば 'sudo apt install python3-pandas' を事前に実行しておきます。

Comment: 詳細なコメントありがとうございます。